# Data does not show in Design Mode

Tags: mvvm-light

I have my models, viewmodels and views setup and binding properly when the program runs, but when in design mode I do not see any of the data or dynamic elements that are controlled by the data.  What could I be missing.  I looked at the sample friends application and did not see anything I was doing different.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Did you find why it wasn't working?

Answer (score 3):

The design view does not support connections to your database, so if your view model constructors are loading any data from a database then this will cause an exception when switching to design view. Consequently, your UI elements will not load properly.

You will, instead, need to load dummy data if your in design mode. You can progamatically check whether or not you're in design mode by using the MVVM-Light Toolkit's ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic property.

For example:

```
ViewModelConstructor()
{
    if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
    {
        // load dummy data
    }
    else
    {
        // load real data from database
    }
}
```

Comment: I should not need to do that because I have a DesignDataService and a DataService and which one I use is handled through the IOC mappings.  In my DesignDataService class all I load is dummy data.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you need to DEBUG why design data is not shown. In most cases, it is because exceptions are thrown somewhere in your code when the designer is executing them. As mentioned by Laurent in his videos, one way is to attach to your Blend process in Visual Studio. I tried this approach in my project and it worked perfectly.

Comment: Do you have the URL to the video you mentioned above?